# How can I pass an unkown number of arguments to C#'s "Database.Open("DatabaseName").Query()" method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have tried Googling to find a solution, but all I get is totally irrelevant results or results involving 2 dimensional arrays, like the one here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb4d54d3-14d7-49e9-b721-db4501db62c8/how-does-one-increment-a-value-in-a-two-dimensional-array, which does not apply.

Say I have this declared:

```
var db = Database.Open("Content");
var searchTerms = searchText.Split('"').Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? element.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) : new string[] { element }).SelectMany(element => element).ToList();
int termCount = searchTerms.Count;
```

(**Note:** *All that you really need to know about `searchTerms` is that it holds a number of search terms typed into a search bar by the user. All the LINQ expression is doing is ensuring that text wrapped in qoutes is treated as a single search term. It is not really necessary to know all of this for the purpose of this question.*)

Then I have compiled (using for loops that loop for each number of items in the `searchTerms` list) a string to be used as a `SELECT` SQL query.

Here is an example that shows part of this string being compiled with the `@0, @1, etc.` placeholders so that my query is parameterized.

```
searchQueryString = "SELECT NULL AS ObjectID, page AS location, 'pageSettings' AS type, page AS value, 'pageName' AS contentType, ";

for (int i=0; i<termCount; i++)
{
    if(i != 0)
    {
        searchQueryString += "+ ";
    }

    searchQueryString += "((len(page) - len(replace(UPPER(page), UPPER(@" + i + "), ''))) / len(@" + i + ")) ";
}

searchQueryString += "AS occurences ";
```

(**Note:** *All that you really need to know about the above code is that I am concatenating the incrementing value of* `i` *to the* `@` *symbol to dynamically compile the placeholder value.*)

All of the above works fine, but later, I must use something along the lines of this (only I don't know how many arguments I will need until runtime):

```
foreach (var row in db.Query(searchQueryString, searchTerms[0]))
{
    @row.occurences
}
```

(**For Clarification:** *I will need a number of additional arguments (i.e., in addition to the* `searchQueryString` *argument) equal to the number of items in the* `searchTerms` *list **AND** they will have to be referencing the correct index (effectively referencing each index from lowest to highest, in order, separated by commas, of course.*)

Also, I will, of course need to use an incrementing value to reference the appropriate index of the list, if I can even get that far, and I don't know how to do that either. Could I use `i++` somehow for that?

I know C# is powerful, but maybe I am asking too much?

Comment: Just a comment, and you may have considered this already, heck, this might even be last resort.  But..., this sounds way too generic.  Is this some kind of generic data layer?  Are you sure this isn't gonna be one of those, "wish I hadn't done that" kinda things down the track somewhere.  Maybe thats all been considered, I'm just trying to be helpful that's all.  There are fantastic ORMs that do all this stuff much better.

Comment: @Mark First of all, thank you for your consideration. I am never and will never (at any point down the road) be happy with a 'gotcha!' moment, so your advice is very welcome, however, this kind of is a 'last resort' kind of thing (mainly because SQL Server CE, which is comes with WebMatrix, doesn't support full text indexing). That having been said, though, I do *not* know what an ORM is.

Comment: Means your query can be written in LINQ rather than SQL.  If EF, you'll work with an object implementing IQueryable.  You can add bits to your where clause in much the same way as you're doing now, but in a much nicer way.  Then, when your execute the ORM writes the actual SQL query for you from how you've setup the IQueryable.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately I don't know that much about LINQ. I need the power of SQLs ORDER BY clause (although, it wouldn't surprise me if LINQ had something very similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for how complex the question probably seemed, the answer ended up being something pretty simple. I suppose it was easy to overlook because I had never done this before and others may have thought it too obvious to be what I was looking for.  However, I had NEVER tried to pass a variable length of parameters before and had no clue if it was even possible or not (okay, well I guess I knew it was possible somehow, but could have been very far from my method for all I knew).

In any case, I had tried:

```
foreach (var row in db.Query(searchQueryString, searchTerms)) //searchTerms is a list of strings.
{
    //Do something for each row returned from the sql query.
}
```

Assuming that if it could handle a variable length number of arguments (remember each argument passed after the first in the `Database.Query()` method is treated as fillers for the placeholders in the query string (e.g., `@0, @1, @2, etc.`) it could accept it from a list if it could from an array.

I couldn't really have been any more wrong with that assumption, as passing a list throws an error. However, I was surprised when I finally broke down, converted the list to an array, and tried passing the array instead of the list.

Indeed, **and here is the short answer to my original question,** if I simply give it an array it works easily (a little too easily, which I suppose is why I was so sure it wouldn't work):

```
string[] searchTermsArray = searchTerms.ToArray();

foreach (var row in db.Query(searchQueryString, searchTermsArray)) //searchTermsArray is an array of strings.
{
    //Do something for each row returned from the sql query.
}
```

The above snippet of code is really all that is needed to successfully answer my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use params keyword for variable numbers of parameters. With params, the arguments passed to a any function are changed by the compiler to elements in a temporary array.

```
static int AddParameters(params int[] values)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (int value in values)
    {
      total += value;
    }
    return total;
}
```

and can be called as

```
int add1 = AddParameters(1);
int add2 = AddParameters(1, 2);
int add3 = AddParameters(1, 2, 3);
int add4 = AddParameters(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

//-----------Edited Reply based on comments below---
You can use something like this to be used with SQL

```
void MYSQLInteractionFunction(String myConnectionString)
 {
    String searchQueryString = "SELECT NULL AS ObjectID, page AS location, 'pageSettings' AS type, page AS value, 'pageName' AS contentType, ";
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(searchQueryString, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader queryCommandReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    // Create a DataTable object to hold all the data returned by the query.
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    // Use the DataTable.Load(SqlDataReader) function to put the results of the query into a DataTable.
    dataTable.Load(queryCommandReader);

    Int32 rowID = 0; // or iterate on your Rows - depending on what you want
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
       myStringList.Add(dataTable.Rows[rowID][column.ColumnName] + " | ");
       rowID++;
     }
     myConnection.Close();

     String[] myStringArray = myStringList.ToArray();
     UnlimitedParameters(myStringArray);
}

static void UnlimitedParameters(params string[] values)
{
    foreach (string strValue in values)
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do with this strValue
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am afraid a little more clarification is needed (I apologize for that), but as you write (for example): `int add3 = SumParameters(1, 2, 3);` I will not *know* how many arguments to include. Maybe I just don't understand your answer yet?

Comment: @VoidKing: that's what `params` does; in this example, you can pass as many `int` values as you need. The method is written to handle whatever number of arguments that get passed in.

Comment: if you are not aware of how many arguments, you need to , you can create a list and fill that in runtime and in the end make an Int Array and pass to this function...

         List<int> myIntList = new List<int>();
         myIntList.Add(2);
         myIntList.Add(3);
         myIntList.Add(4);

         int[] myIntArray = myIntList.ToArray();
         int mySum = AddParameters(myIntArray);

Comment: I am very glad to hear that this is possible, I thank you very much for your help, and I hate to trouble you further, but this is the first time I have ever been introduced to `params`. If you could append to your answer an example of what I would need to do before and during the call of the actual `db.Query(searchQueryString, argument1, argument2, etc., etc.)` method, I will gladly upvote and accept if it works. My plan is to go over this line by line so that I can better understand how the code works.

Comment: Also keep in mind that my `searchTerms` list is a list of strings, not integers (if that even matters) that are search terms that I am testing against in my database.

Comment: In case you don't already know, the `db.Query()` method returns a list with items equal to each row returned from the `searchQueryString` sql query. The arguments that follow are the values that will fill the placeholders in the query string (order is all important here), effectively protecting against SQL injection.

Comment: Am going to lunch, will be back in 1 hour, and this post will be the first thing I check. Thanks again for all your help and any more you can provide!

Comment: Okay, just got back from lunch, looking over this now. Wow! it looks like there may be bit in here I am not familiar with. This might take a sec. Thanks for adding more to your post!

Comment: I guess, I am still having trouble wrapping my mind around this. It seems like you are making a custom method that accepts any number of parameters (useful information, to be sure), but I already have a method that accepts any number of arguments (C#'s `Database.Open("DatabaseName").Query()`). What I need is to pass an *"unkown-until-runtime"* amount of arguments to that method. Am I still confused? Either way, this answer is definitely worth an upvote already, which is exactly what I'm gonna do now.

Comment: Also, I've changed the title of the question to better reflect the real question I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you need from the question, but it looks like you're substituting a series of placeholders in the SQL with another value. If that's the case, you can use String.Format to replace the values like this:

```
        object val = "a";
        object anotherVal = 2.0;
        var result = string.Format("{0} - {1}", new[] { val, anotherVal });
```

This way, you can substitute as many values as you need by simply creating the arguments array to be the right size.

If you're creating a SQL query on the fly, then you need to be wary of SQL injection, and substituting user-supplied text directly into a query is a bit of a no-no from this point of view. The best way to avoid this is to use parameters in the query, which automatically then get sanitised to prevent SQL injection. You can still use a 'params array' argument though, to achieve what you need, for example:

```
    public IDataReader ExecuteQuery(string sqlQuery, params string[] searchTerms)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand { CommandText = sqlQuery };

        for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.Length; i++)
        {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(i.ToString(), searchTerms[i]);
        }

        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

obviously, you could also build up the sql string within this method if you needed to, based on the length of the searchTerms array

Comment: I have updated my question for (hopefully) a little more clarification.

Comment: Does your answer still apply? Did you see my **For Clarification** note?

Comment: OMG I think I just realized what you are doing! It seems perfect for my scenario, however, I have one major question that MUST be answered before (and definitely BEFORE) I use it. Will using String.Format in this way protect against SQL injection as efficiently as using the parameterized query in my above example?

Comment: Using string.Format will NOT protect against SQL injection. It's a bad idea.

Comment: Hi @VoidKing, if you're using this approach to create dynamic SQL, then inserting the values in this way will not prevent SQL injection. I've added an example to the answer of creating a Sql Command using an arbitrary number of parameters.

Comment: @JonG Oh, believe me, I know all about using parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. That is the whole reason that I need the placeholders in the sql string (which I have successfully dynamically compiled within the string using loops and some conditional logic for the unknown number of parameters and other sql syntax). Back to what you added to your answer, I will try this and get back with you.

Comment: No, it seems I cannot use `params string[] searchTerms` in a standard C#.net-webpages (razor) environment, as such. It has to be something that can be passed to: `foreach(var row in db.Query(searchQueryString, param1, param2, etc., etc.)){//do stuff for each entry found in database (i.e., the list returned)}`

Comment: params array allows you to have a variable length argument list, it's as though there is an unlimited number of optional parameters at the end of the function definition, so you can use ExecuteQuery(q, p1, p2) or ExecuteQuery(q, p1, p2, p3) or ExecuteQuery(q, p1, p2, p3, p4, etc...). Also, you can pass an array, so ExecuteQuery(q, new[] { p1, p2, p3}) is also a valid way to use this function, which would be appropriate if the client didn't know at compile time how many arguments to pass.

Comment: @JonG I tried this using this syntax `db.Query(queryString, searchTerms)` Where `searchTerms` is a C# List. I could convert my list to an array and try that (when I finally get the syntax right for it, that is). I guess I can't pass a list here.